# Fixing a baking blunder

Tags: eggs, cake

I added too much butter to a cake batter and ended up with a stiff dough.  Thought I could try to save the dough and turn it into shortbread. The cake batter called for 6 egg whites and the shortbread recipe calls for 3 whole eggs. Should I add some yolks or whole eggs to correct the batter?

Comment: It's rare for shortbread to have eggs. You might still be able to convert into a cookie/biscuit or a slice of some sort, just not shortbread. I think you'd have to add more flour and more liquid to make the cake work, but not sure on conversion to others.

Comment: Can we get the original (messed up) recipe, to get an idea of what ingredients at what ratio are in the mix already?

Comment: Hi Stephanie, I have already calculated what I need to add to the mix for dry ingredients. I mistakenly added double the amount of butter.  It called for 6 egg whites, which I did.  The shortbread recipe I am trying to turn it into calls for 3 whole eggs. I need to know if I should add any yokes or a whole egg to make the correction. In my research, I found that 6 whites can be substituted

Comment: for 3 whole eggs but it seems to me that it might require yolks for binding?

Comment: thanks so much,

Answer (score -1):

If there is too much butter in the cake, you can add drying ingredients such as egg whites, flour, or baking powder to the mix. Too much butter can make the cake greasy and leave you with a runny consistency. Alternatively, you can put your cake in the oven for a few extra minutes to reduce the moisture.

Comment: Thank you, Rehana! Will be doing that.